# Como determinar permissão de uso de tabelas?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, segurança

Como posso fazer para um certo usuário "ver" umas tabelas e outro não?
Andei pesquisando, encontrei o `DENY SELECT ON ***` porém não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de fazer isso é através da própria *GUI* do SQL Server Management Studio.

Obs: Descreverei passo a passo utilizando como referência o 2008, mas acredito que eles sejam similares caso esteja utilizando outra versão.

Para **negar permissões** específicas de uma tabela ao usuário você pode fazer o seguinte:

- No pesquisador de objetos, vá em Segurança -> Logons e clique para criar um novo.
- Depois de definir o nome e a senha desejados, clique na aba "Mapeamento de Usuário" e selecione o banco ao qual ele terá acesso (se preferir, selecione a função desejada i.g. db_datareader, db_backupoperator etc).
- No pesquisador de objetos, vá em Banco de dados -> Banco desejado -> Segurança -> Usuários e acesse as propriedades do usuário em questão.
- Vá à aba "Protegíveis" e clique em pesquisar.
- Selecione "Todos os objetos dos tipos..." e, em seguida, selecione "Tabelas".
- Agora que todas as tabelas do banco foram listadas, basta clicar sobre as quais você deseja conceder/negar permissões e marcar as *checkboxes*.

---

Supondo que um usuário `user` **possa fazer uma consulta** em tabelas dos *schemas* `dbo` e `sync`, a permissão ficaria:

```
USE seuBanco;

GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::sync TO [user];
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [user];
```

Supondo ainda que este usuário **não possa efetuar o *drop*** em tabelas do *schema* `sync`, 
bastaria negar a permissão através do [DENY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176128.aspx):

```
DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::sync TO [user];
```

Contudo, como negar a [permissão](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx) `ALTER` afeta a possibilidade do usuário criar e alterar objetos de um *schema*, uma alternativa seria usar um *trigger* que agisse em todas as tabelas do seu banco.

Para isso, bastaria verificar se o usuário logado é `user` e se a tabela que está sofrendo o *drop* pertence ao *schema* `sync`:

```
USE seuBanco;

CREATE TRIGGER deny_drop ON DATABASE FOR DROP_TABLE -- Cria o gatilho para todas as tabelas do banco.
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @data XML = EVENTDATA(); -- Armazena informações sobre o evento.
    DECLARE @schema NVARCHAR(255) = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',
        'NVARCHAR(255)'); -- Obtém o schema da tabela que está sofrendo o drop.
    DECLARE @usuario VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT SYSTEM_USER); -- Obtém o usuário atual do banco.

    IF (@usuario = 'user' and @schema = 'sync')
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Drop negado.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; -- Encerra o drop, impedindo que ele seja efetuado.
    END
END
```

**Leitura complementar**:

[Usando gatilhos *DDL* para capturar mudanças de *schema*.](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-2005-to-capture-schema-changes)

Comment: Sim, havia visto essa opção (sql2012) porém, eu consegui negar permissões de update e etc. Mas o que eu preciso é negar permissão de DROP TABLE. Ele pode fazer tudo, só não pode dar drop em um schema. Tenho dois schemas, dbo e sync. Dois usuários: user e sync. O user tem poder para ver o schema dbo e sync, mas o user user não tem poder para dar drop em tabela do schema sync.

Comment: Você pode negar a exclusão desmarcando a *checkbox* da permissão explícita "Excluir" das tabelas pelo modo gráfico ou utilizando o [DENY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176128.aspx): `DENY DELETE ON SCHEMA::sync TO [user];`

Comment: Mas DELETE não é mesmo comando que DROP TABLE, não?

Comment: Não havia achado uma permissão específica para o `DROP` naquela sessão da documentação e fiz uma presunção errada; na verdade, basta substituir `DENY DELETE` por `DENY ALTER`. Contudo, negar a permissão `alter` significa também restringir o usuário quanto a possibilidade de criar e alterar as tabelas do seu `schema`.

Comment: Adicionei à resposta uma possível alternativa.

Comment: Irei testar mais tarde amigo! Agradeço!!!! Creio que irá funcionar sim.